# How to synchronize specific processes in MPI?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, mpi4py

I am running a parallel code using MPI (written in Python, using MPI module mpi4py). I would like to synchronize a subset of processes within MPI_COMM_WORLD, ideally without creating a new communicator.

The function comm.Barrier() blocks processes until a matching call is made by all processes in the communicator **comm**. I would like to do the same thing, but only block 2 specific processes within **comm**. It seems to me that I should be able to synchronize a subset of processes of MPI_COMM_WORLD without creating a new communicator (after all, I can *send a message* between a subset of processes).

It appears such a task cannot be done by Barrier(). Is there another method I could use to synchronize two specific processes without creating a new communicator?

Comment: If there are only 2 tasks, then `MPI_Sendrecv()` is a good fit

Comment: This smells like a XY problem. Please give more background as to what you really want to achieve. **Why** do you not want to create a communicator? **Why** do you want to *synchronize* two processes without having to send data around? Most barriers are useless in the first place.

Comment: Thank you both. I am debugging a code containing many Send and Recv calls, which runs on 10000+ MPI processes. I must determine how long the Send and Recv calls take to actually *transfer* the data. When I profile the code now, I measure very long Recv times, because the processes spend much time waiting at Recv calls for the sender process to reach the Send. For example, I have measured Bcast *transfer* times by placing barriers like so: Barrier, Tick, Bcast, Barrier, Tock. I would prefer to not create new communicators because I would need ~10000^2 communicators.

Comment: For that, you should use a MPI performance analysis a tool! For example Score-P / Vampir.

Comment: Thanks. I am limited to the software installed on the supercomputer on which I must run/debug the code (an IBM Blue Gene/Q), which does not include Score-P or Vampir. Perhaps it has another debugger useful for MPI specifically.